# ActiveRecord validate.Undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a make view "_error_messages".But browser show me error

> undefined local variable or method `event'

```
This is my partial _error_messages:
<% if event.errors.any? %>  
<div id="errorExplanation">  
    <h2> В форме обнаружено <%= pluralize(event.errors.count, "ошибка", "ошибки") %>:</h2>  
  <ul>  
  <% event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
    <li><%= msg %></li>  
  <% end %>  
  </ul>  
</div>  
<% end %>
```

this is my partial _event_form:

```
<%= form_for event, html: { class: "event-form" } do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
<% unless current_user %>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <%= label :email, "Введите Ваш email:" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :email, "",class: "form-control" %>
          <small>Он нужен для того, что бы Вы могли позже отредактировать добавленное Вами событие.</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly passing event to the partial?

Like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', event: event %>
```

Or this:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: { event: event } %>
```

If the error isn't on the partial but in the view itself, check if you're not missing a `@` before the events variable or if it should be a method.

Comment: Thank you, error does not show, but does not show validation error.
Where can I see problem?

Comment: Your view looks good, maybe `event` doesn't have any errors? Try printing it on the html like this <%= event.errors.inspect %>

Comment: The model is empty but it does not contain any errors. You may want to take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html